# 360 Video Environment

Tags: texturing, video, world, hdri

I am making an animation in which I need to have a 360 video in the background as the environment texture in World panel instead of an HDRi. Is there any way to so this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yep. Just convert the video into an *image sequence* and load it into an *Environment Texture* node as usual. Make sure you have 'Auto Refresh' enabled.