# 360 video as environment background

Tags: node-editor

I've tried loading the video in an environment texture node but it only displays the first frame of the video.

So, I tried another way: based on this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/115485/360-video-environment) I extracted a sequence of images from the video, but I can only import one of them in the environment texture node.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to the forum! Could you please add a screenshot of your node setup or provide your blend file using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ?

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and go to "Texture", and choose "Image Sequence". Then open the folder where the images are stored, press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all of them and then add the sequence.